# Firebase create record not working on PROD

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, netlify

I have a blog application built with nextjs and hosted on netlify. I have a contact form from which the record gets inserted into Firebase.
The creation of record works fine on localhost:3000 when running the app through the below mentioned commands in VSCODE.

```
npm run dev
npm run start
```

But the records are not getting inserted from the form when I deploy my nextjs app on netlify. I have put console.log() in my functions in the catch block but the errors are not getting displayed in the netlify function logs.

My Contacts API Code is -

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";
import initFirebase from "../../firebase/initFirebase";


let success;
const contact = async (req, res) => {
  initFirebase();
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(<username>,<password>)
    .then(user=>{
      success=false
      if(user.user.uid)
      firebase.database().ref('contacts').child(user.user.uid).push().set(req.body)
      .then(()=>{success==true})
      .catch((err)=>{success=false;console.log(err)});
    })
    .catch((err) => {(success = false);console.log(err);});
  return res.status(200).json();
};
export default contact;
```

The initFirebase() is defined as per the below mentioned code -

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
// the below imports are option - comment out what you don't need
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/storage'
import 'firebase/analytics'
import 'firebase/performance'

const clientCredentials = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
}

export default function initFirebase() {
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp(clientCredentials)
        
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            
            if ('measurementId' in clientCredentials) {
                firebase.analytics()
                firebase.performance()
            }
        }
        console.log('Firebase was successfully init.')
    }
}
```

Just looked into the logs in the netlify functions and it shows -

```
[t [Error]: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.] {
  code: 'auth/network-request-failed',
  a: null
}
8:31:07 PM: 0430113e INFO   [request] /api/contact
```

I have added my domain in the Firebase Authorized Domains.

Any help with troubleshooting the problem is much appreciated.

Comment: None of the code you shared calls any Firebase API, so it's hard to say based on that where the problem is coming from. I strongly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there maximizes the chance that someone can help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen As suggested I have added the code for reference.